# Is it possible to access a query term in a script field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to construct an elasticsearch query in which I can search for a term and on-the-fly compute a new field for each found document, which is calculated based on some existing fields as well as the query term. Is this possible?

For example, let's say in my EL query I am searching for documents which have the keyword "amsterdam" in the "text" field.

```
"filter": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "text": {
              "query": "amsterdam"
            }
          }
        }]
```

Now I would also like to have a script field in my query, which computes some value based on other fields as well as the query.
So far, I have only found how to access the other fields of a document though, using doc['someOtherField'], for example

```
 "script_fields" : {
        "new_field" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "if (doc['citizens'].value > 10000) { 
                           return "large";
                           }
                           return "small";"
            }
        }
   }
```

How can I integrate the query term, e.g. if I wanted to add to the if statement "if the query term starts with a-e"?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track but [`script_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-fields.html#script-fields) are primarily used to post-process your documents' attributes — they won't help you filter any docs because they're run *after* the query phase.

With that being said, you *can* use scripts to filter your documents through [script queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html). Before you do that, though, you should explore alternatives.

In other words, scripts should be used when all other mechanisms and techniques have been exhausted.

#### Back to your example. I see three possibilities off the top of my head.

1. [Match phrase prefix queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) as a group of bool-should subqueries:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "text_field": "a"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "text_field": "b"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "text_field": "c"
                }
              },
              ... till the letter "e"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. A `regexp` query:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "regexp": {
           "text_field": "[a-e].+"
         }
       }
     ] 
    }
  }
}
```

3. Script queries using `.charAt` comparisons:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                char c = doc['text_field.keyword'].value.charAt(0);
                return c >= params.gte.charAt(0) && c <= params.lte.charAt(0);
              """,
              "params": {
                "gte": "a",
                "lte": "e"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you're relatively new to ES and would love to see real-world examples, check out my recently released [Elasticsearch Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/). One chapter is dedicated to scripting and as it turns out, you can achieve *a lot* with scripts (if of course executed properly).

Comment: Thanks, that already clarifies it a bit. I actually DO want to post-process though. Really what I would like to have is a dynamic field, whose value is only computed once a query has been performed as the field needs the query for the computation. 
So if my query (match-phrase) is "amsterdam", I want to get all documents satisfying this query. And then for each of these documents, the dynamic field if filled with a value according to some script, which takes into account the query "amsterdam" as well as other (static) document fields.

Comment: But this should also work for any other query term, so continuing with my example, if the query term happens to be "amsterdam", then the dynamic field of each doc (matching "amsterdam") has value "large" if the doc has citizens>10000 and "small" otherwise. If the query term happens to be "london" then for ever returned doc (matching "london"), the dynamic field will just be "small" (since the query term "london" does not start with a-e).

Comment: Gotcha. Well script fields would support the syntax from my 3rd example with the addition of `params['_source']` which is disabled in standard script queries. Do let me know if this brings you further to your solution or if you need some more info.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how params[_source] helps me... As far as I understand params[_source] lets me access fields of a document similar to doc[], just that it also works for complex types of fields. What I want to access though is not a field in a document, it is the query term in my search query, so I want to access filter.query_term.text. Any idea if this is even possible?

Comment: Oh I see. No that's not possible. But you can provide it thru `"params"` when you construct your `query`.